# Hangman program for loop in c++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop

First off, I am writing a program using user defined functions and a while loop. My user defined function getNextWord() generates a random word from a file for my user to use for the hangman game. My next step in my program is to check the guesses of the user. I am trying to do this using a while loop within the while loop is a for statement that is not working correctly. I am assuming that using the function getNextWord() as the test expression is not right. I tried using a cin >> word to put the generated word into a variable but that is not working right either. How can I write this loop so that it is checking a letter in the generated word to a letter the user guesses?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm> 
using namespace std;

#include "randword.h"
#include "myfuncts.h"

const string boardOne = " ------|\n |     |\n       |\n         |\n            |\n    -------\n\n";
const string boardTwo = " ------|\n |     |\n 0     |\n       |\n           |\n    -------\n\n";
const string boardThree = " ------|\n |     |\n 0     |\n |     |\n       |\n    -------\n\n";
const string boardFour = " ------|\n |     |\n 0     |\n-|     |\n       |\n    -------\n\n";
const string boardFive = " ------|\n |     |\n 0     |\n-|-    |\n       |\n    -------\n\n";
const string boardSix = " ------|\n |     |\n 0     |\n-|-    |\n  \\    |\n    -------\n\n";
const string boardSeven = " ------|\n |     |\n 0     |\n-|-    |\n/ \\    |\n    -------\n\n";

int main()
{
    // Declarations
    string fileWord; 
    int wrongGuess = 0;
    char letterGuess = 0;
    string playerYN;
    string word;

getWords("hangman.dat");

cout << "\nDo you want to play hangman? (y or n): ";
cin >> playerYN; 
PromptYN(playerYN);

getNextWord();
cout << "\n\nWord to Guess: " << getNextWord() << endl;

cout << "\n" << boardOne << endl;

while (wrongGuess != 6)
{
    cout << "\nEnter a letter to guess: ";
    cin >> letterGuess;
    letterGuess = toupper(letterGuess);
    cout << "You guessed the letter: " << letterGuess << endl;
    bool found = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < getNextWord().length(); i++)
    {
        if (getNextWord()[i] == letterGuess)
        {
            cout << "\n" << letterGuess << " is in the letter to guess." << endl;
            found = true;
            if (wrongGuess == 0)
                cout <<  "\n" << boardOne << endl;
            if (wrongGuess == 1)
                cout << "\n" << boardTwo << endl;
            if (wrongGuess == 2)
                cout << "\n" << boardThree << endl;
            if (wrongGuess == 3)
                cout << "\n" << boardFour << endl;
            if (wrongGuess == 4)
                cout << "\n" << boardFive << endl;
            if (wrongGuess == 5)
                cout << "\n" << boardSix << endl;
            if (wrongGuess == 6)
                cout << "\n" << boardSeven << endl;
        }

    }
    // if not found - increment wrong guesses
    if (!found)
    {
        wrongGuess++;
        cout << "\n" << letterGuess << " is not in the word to guess." << endl;
        //print the board that corresponds to the wrongGuess

        if (wrongGuess == 0)
            cout << "\n" << boardOne << endl;
        if (wrongGuess == 1)
            cout << "\n" << boardTwo << endl;
        if (wrongGuess == 2)
            cout << "\n" << boardThree << endl;
        if (wrongGuess == 3)
            cout << "\n" << boardFour << endl;
        if (wrongGuess == 4)
            cout << "\n" << boardFive << endl;
        if (wrongGuess == 5)
            cout << "\n" << boardSix << endl;
        if (wrongGuess == 6)
            cout << "\n" << boardSeven << endl;
    }
}


cout << "\n\n";
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

also here is the function definition for the user defined function

```
string getNextWord()
{
    int randomNum = 0;
    string word;


if (Used > 0)
{
    randomNum = rand() % Used;

    word = Words[randomNum];

    Words[randomNum] = Words[Used - 1];
    Used--;
    std::transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), toupper);
    return(word);
}
else
    return("");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Note what happens here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < getNextWord().length(); i++)
{
    if (getNextWord()[i] == letterGuess)
```

The repeated calls to `getNextWord` will get new words. This keeps moving the goalposts on the player since every time they go to test a letter, it's against a different word. Be a heck of a frustrating game.

What OP wants to do is call `getNextWord` once per game and store the result. For example,

```
string wordToGuess = getNextWord();
cout << "\nEnter a letter to guess: ";
cin >> letterGuess;
letterGuess = toupper(letterGuess);
cout << "You guessed the letter: " << letterGuess << endl;
bool found = false;

for (int i = 0; i < wordToGuess.length(); i++)
{
    if (wordToGuess[i] == letterGuess)
    {
```

## Off topic:

This code can be turned into a function that is called from the main routine rather than being repeated:

```
if (wrongGuess == 0)
    cout <<  "\n" << boardOne << endl;
if (wrongGuess == 1)
    cout << "\n" << boardTwo << endl;
if (wrongGuess == 2)
    cout << "\n" << boardThree << endl;
...
```

It can also be rewritten to use a switch statement or, better, an array. The array is defined up at the top of the file in place of `boardOne` through `boardSeven`

```
const string boards[] = 
{
    " ------|\n |     |\n       |\n         |\n            |\n    -------\n\n",
    " ------|\n |     |\n 0     |\n       |\n           |\n    -------\n\n",
    " ------|\n |     |\n 0     |\n |     |\n       |\n    -------\n\n",
    " ------|\n |     |\n 0     |\n-|     |\n       |\n    -------\n\n",
    " ------|\n |     |\n 0     |\n-|-    |\n       |\n    -------\n\n",
    " ------|\n |     |\n 0     |\n-|-    |\n  \\    |\n    -------\n\n",
    " ------|\n |     |\n 0     |\n-|-    |\n/ \\    |\n    -------\n\n"
};
```

and then used

```
cout << boards[wrongGuess] << endl
```

### Off topic, continued:

The data definitions which define the boards can be more readable. In C++ we can split a string literal into one or more adjacent string literals, which do not have to be on the same line. For instance, these two definitions are equivalent:

```
const string name = "John Doe";
const string name = "John "
                    "Doe";
```

with this in mind, we can write

```
const string boardOne = " ------|\n"
                        " |     |\n"
                        "       |\n"
                        "         |\n"
                        "            |\n"
                        "    -------\n\n";
```

This way we, in the text editor, we can see the picture as it will be laid out on the console when the program outputs the string.  If something is 
wrong, it is visually obvious and easy to fix.

Once you get the game working, you may want to tweak the appearance of the boards, which will likely be time-wasting and frustrating with the current layout.

Comment: Thank you for a very worth-while addition, @kaz

Comment: No problem; who can resist off topic, ya know?